# Getting styles of element and all descendants/children

Tags: javascript, css

I have a panel on a web page that I need to print separate from the rest of the page and unfortunately the CSS for the page is not done in a way that will allow for a print stylesheet. I am trying to copy the content of the panel to a new tab and trigger print on that tab but the problem is that none of the styles get copied over. How would I get the css styles applied to an element and all children/descendants of that element so I can copy them over to this new tab also?

```
var prtContent = document.getElementById("ProjectDataAssessmentPanel");
var styles = dumpCssText(prtContent);  // need the implementation for this function                  
var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0,width=800,height=900,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
WinPrint.document.write("<style type='text/css'>" + styles + "</style>");
WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
WinPrint.document.close();
WinPrint.focus();
WinPrint.print();
WinPrint.close();
```